# Error: "domain option is required" when deploying to Azure with Next.js app

Tags: azure, deployment, next.js, environment-variables, auth0

I'm having an issue when deploying a Next.js app to Azure using **Azure Web Apps** I encounter an error with Auth0 when deploying my app, it complains issue with a Domain is required.

**This is the output of my GitHub actions when deploying:**

```
Using browser-only version of superagent in non-browser environment
(node:1647) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: domain option is required
    at attribute (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:45555)
    at Object.check (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:46043)
    at new WebAuth (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:128155)
    at Object.7531 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/chunks/680.js:28:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.3443 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/chunks/443.js:22:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.1836 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/pages/_app.js:66:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/pages/_app.js:911:39)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:1647) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:1647) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:1647) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: domain option is required
    at attribute (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:45555)
    at Object.check (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:46043)
    at new WebAuth (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:128155)
    at Object.7531 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/chunks/680.js:28:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.3443 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/chunks/443.js:22:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.1836 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/pages/_app.js:66:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/pages/_app.js:911:39)
(node:1647) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)

> Build error occurred
Error: domain option is required
    at attribute (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:45555)
    at Object.check (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:46043)
    at new WebAuth (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/node_modules/auth0-js/dist/auth0.min.js:8:128155)
    at Object.7531 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/chunks/680.js:28:15)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.3443 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/chunks/443.js:22:13)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at Object.1836 (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/pages/_app.js:66:17)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/home/runner/work/app-admin/app-admin/.next/server/pages/_app.js:911:39) {
  type: 'Error'
}
```

### Things I already done

- I added my .env keys to Azure called "application settings"
- I have the Github Actions configured from my Github Repo to my Web app in Azure
- Locally I have a `.env` file where I defined my keys

### My github action workflow.yml file

```
 name: Build and deploy Node.js app to Azure Web App - app-admin
    on:
      push:
        branches:
          - develop
      workflow_dispatch:
 
   
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js version
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '14.x'

      - name: npm install, build, and test
        run: |
          npm install
          npm run build --if-present
          npm run test --if-present
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app
          path: .

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: node-app

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        with:
          app-name: 'app-admin'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_F1A195F9AA334F72B824DDFFC4053295 }}
          package: .
```

What am I missing here? I'll appreciate your help!

Comment: Configure environment variables in your GitHub action (`build` job) too. Refer this: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables Also, don't hardcode them, use `${{ secrets.FOO }}` syntax. Secrets can be set at https://github.com/org/repo/settings/secrets/actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the error trace this is some configuration issue where we need to set the domain for our webapp. Check for the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/custom-domain?tabs=azure-dns) on how to setup a custom domain in Webapp.

Also as suggested from the comment, we can set default environment variables in GitHub that are available to every step in a workflow run.

[Documentations](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/environment-variables) to check the variables.